# How can I check whether an integer is within 5 numbers of a hidden random integer?

Tags: java, random

My project is a lucky guess game, I have created the code to generate a random number, and the user is trying to guess it. On the third and final attempt, I need a condition that checks whether the final guess is within 5 (both below and above) this random number.

Due to plagiarism concerns in my university, I will not be posting my code but I will note that my random number is assigned a named variable (`randomNumber`).

Is there something like: `if (guess.isWithin(5) = randomNumber)`

I know that's gibberish but hopefully you get what I mean.

Comment: I'm new to this site so have many things to learn, but why is this question being downvoted? Seems good to me.

Answer (score 4):

You could check the absolute difference between the two numbers:

```
if (Math.abs(randomNumber - guess) <= 5) {
    // Is within five...
```

Answer (score 3):

The *expression* `Math.abs(a - b) <= c` is the idiomatic way of testing if `a` and `b` are within `c` of each other.

So in your case, something like

```
if (Math.abs(yourGuess - randomDrawing) <= 5){
    /*the guess is within 5*/
```

will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

`Math.abs` check is the best way as @Mureinik mentioned.
Let me also add uncommon way to check.

Appache Commons has [`Range`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/Range.html) class:

```
Range<Integer> range = Range.between(randomNumber - 5, randomNumber + 5);
range.contains(guess);
```

Guava has [`Range`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) class too:

```
Range<Integer> range = Range.closed(randomNumber - 5, randomNumber + 5);
range.contains(guess);
```